# Using a variable (from a property) in SQL script

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot

Can I put placeholders in an SQL script (that initializes data for my Spring Boot application which uses PostgreSQL)? Suppose I have this query:

```
INSERT INTO users (id, name, email) VALUES (1, 'John', ?);
```

Now, here's the way I initialize the data:

```
    @Bean
    public DataSourceInitializer dataSourceInitializer(@Qualifier("dataSource") final DataSource dataSource) {
        log.info("Executing SQL scripts from '/resources/' folder...");
        ResourceDatabasePopulator resourceDatabasePopulator = new ResourceDatabasePopulator();
        resourceDatabasePopulator.addScript(new ClassPathResource("/delete.sql"));
        resourceDatabasePopulator.addScript(new ClassPathResource("/schema.sql"));
        resourceDatabasePopulator.addScript(new ClassPathResource("/data.sql"));

        DataSourceInitializer dataSourceInitializer = new DataSourceInitializer();
        dataSourceInitializer.setDataSource(dataSource);
        dataSourceInitializer.setDatabasePopulator(resourceDatabasePopulator);
        return dataSourceInitializer;
    }
```

First, I drop all tables (using `delete.sql`). Secondly, I create the tables anew (`schema.sql`). Finally, I populate tables with `data.sql`.

Now, I also have a property in `application.properties`: `default.email=example@domain.com`. I'd like the value of this property to be injected into the placeholder in SQL script.

Can I somehow do that?